# Advisability of including server-side information in JSON in an Ajax request

Tags: javascript, json, yui, security

I'm working on a materials exchange site for instructors and students.  The material is confidential in the sense that it's ours and we don't want other instructors to steal it. On the other hand, it has no personal or sensitive information so security is not a huge concern.  If you steal my grammar exercise, I'm not going to sue you.  I'm using Ion Auth in a Codeigniter framework and am satisfied with that.  I use YUI 2.8 to display editable datatables and editable trees.  Building on the Codeigniter MVC framework I have a controller to handle Ajax requests.  When I post a request via the YUI Connection class I pass a serialised object called `data` as the only parameter, which comes from a JSON object assembled on the client side by passing a config object to `YAHOO.si.factory.Method` like this:

```
addTreeNode: new YAHOO.si.factory.Method({
    className: "instructors_model",
    methodName: "add_exercise_tree_node",
    key: "id",
    mode: "child",
    fields: ['n0', 'n1','n2', 'n3'],
    params: [{
        key: "nodeData",
        name: "nodeData",
        type: "text",
        direction: "IN",
        value: "34"
    },{
        key: "name",
        name: "name",
        type: "text",
        direction: "IN",
        value: "Grammar"
    }],
    success: "You have successfully added a node to the tree."      
}),
```

The controller parses the JSON string assembled by `YAHOO.si.factory.Method` and figures out that it has to call `add_exercise_tree_node` in the `instructors_model` and pass 2 parameters.  The `add_exercise_tree_node` method does the dirty work on the database and, hopefully, returns a success message.  If so, the success message is displayed on the client side and the tree is updated to include the new node.

My question is, am I giving away too much information about the server in this plain-text querystring?  It's a post so it doesn't appear in the URL, but of course it's completely visible in something like the Firebug console.

The question behind that question of course is what do you security experts out there advise about parcelling out responsibility for Ajax in an MVC framework?  I want the manageability of having just one controller responsible for handling Ajax requests, so I've ended up with a slightly complicated (and insecure?) overloading on the client-side.  What patterns do you advise for this?

Comment: Are you exposing too much of the internal API and could someone use that to reconstruct your app? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: `what do you security experts out there advise about parcelling out responsibility for Ajax in an MVC framework?` I advise not being "more clever" than the guys who wrote the framework. However, what you suggested `I want the manageability of having just one controller responsible for handling Ajax requests` while closeminded (you're defeating the RESTful purpose of MVC) is viable.

Comment: @jcolebrand Exactly. Although the app is only intended for known users with accounts, the security is very light so I wondered to what extent this approach would make an app vulnerable to a hacker's attack.

Comment: A dedicated person will always be able to reverse engineer your product. Do what seems reasonable with the time budget you have and move forward.

Comment: @jcolebrand Scouring through links on Google to find something digestible that would help me understand MVC, REST, Ajax and put them together sensibly. It's a minefield.  Can you recommend a link with a good explanation of that *huge* idea "you're defeating the RESTful purpose of MVC". I thought MVC was a lot older than REST and didn't know that MVC was supposed to be RESTful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061374/mvc-in-node-and-general-how-are-models-tied-to-views is part of where I answered this earlier, but let me explain it for what you're asking here, tailored to your situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My claim in the comments was that you're defeating the purpose of RESTful architecture in the MVC paradigm, primarily with focus on "all AJAX calls go to one controller". So let's tear this down into something usable, and then rebuild our understanding of why/how.

REST just means [REpresentational State Transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) but that's not what we *mean* when we say REST or RESTful. We mean that we intend each URL to represent a type of resource, and we use [verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) to indicate what we're doing with each request. So "GET", "POST", "PUT", etc all have a purpose, and we use that purpose to dictate how we interact with the individual resources.

So let's put that into perspective, let's do something with that; consider an HR application (this is one of those easy ones that people adopt). We have People and Departments. Departments have an ID, a Name, and a Manager (who is a Person). People have an ID, a Name, a Manager (may be -1 in our system to indicate no manager, or an ID of a person) and a Phone Number.

When we HTTP GET http://server.domain/app/Person we get a directory of all people, that gives us their name and ID.

```
[ {Name: "Cole Brand", ID: 1}, {Name: "user341180", ID: 2} ]
```

When we HTTP GET http://server.domain/app/Person/1 we get

```
{ Name: "Cole Brand", ID: 1, Manager: -1, "Phone Number": "222-555-1234" }
```

When we HTTP GET http://server.domain/app/Person/2 we get

```
{ Name: "user341180", ID: 2, Manager: 1, "Phone Number": "222-555-6789" }
```

And just for the sake of completeness, a list of departments:

HTTP GET http://server.domain/app/Department/

```
{ Name: "HR", Manager: 1 }
```

Now obviously, my example is a little dry, because for instance, the employees certainly work in a department, but I haven't associated them to it by their profile. Surely the database would track that, but we don't have it here. This is a simple example.

So you can see from this that there is no HTML being returned. We will come back to that.

For the next part, notice that I've kept using HTTP GET. What if we used HTTP POST? That would mean that whatever we passed, would overwrite that data. So let me give a brief example:

HTTP POST http://server.domain/app/Person/2

```
send this data in the post body { Manager: -1, "Phone Number": "222-555-0089" }
get nothing in response (we could return the object, but my API doesn't for whatever reason, call it a specification deficiency)
```

When we HTTP GET http://server.domain/app/Person/2 we now get

```
{ Name: "user341180", ID: 2, Manager: -1, "Phone Number": "222-555-0089" }
```

See how we used HTTP POST to *update* the record? That's how we use our RESTful methods, we use the verb to indicate the action.

So what else could we use to communicate with the server? What if we wanted to have the RESTful methods return both a webpage and the data, but for GET? We could use an HTTP HEADER (maybe an X-Header?) to specify that we're making a data call, so by default we make a request to HTTP GET http://server.domain/app/Person/1 and we get a webpage. If you would like an example of that (a rest response providing a webpage) check the page we're on now. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061912/` <-- is actually served by MVC restful principles (but I don't think they supply the JSON by this method, because that's not how their system is setup).

So I'm probably scrambling you all up, I just wanted to review REST, and how we use it today for MVC purposes. Let's look at part of that again, the part where we do http://server.domain/app/Person

In MVC terms, that would mean that we've got a Person controller in our app. Any requests made against the Person controller would be routed based on their verb type first, then any additional parameters next. For instance, submitting this answer makes a post to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061912/answer/submit`. So the Controller knows that it expects to receive "Post ID" (so it knows the parent that the answer belongs to), "answer" telling it that I'm adding an answer, and "submit" so it knows what I'm doing. If I were editing it would be an edit-submit instead of answer/submit.

Ok, so I feel like I'm making things confusing, and I don't know if you read my answer on [MVC in node and general: How are models tied to views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061374/mvc-in-node-and-general-how-are-models-tied-to-views/11061392#11061392) but let me clarify: The Controller is a routing device to take input, send it to the appropriate model, and then render some view (HTML, JSON, XML, plain text, etc). Note that rendering a view is not required (remember my crappy API that didn't return anything on a HTTP POST?).

So now we get to the point of what I was trying to get at in my response earlier, which I'm still not being clear enough on. When you move methods from the "appropriate resource" (in the case of this post /question/), you're breaking the idea that one URL root is one resource. Oy, I've messed this all up haven't I?

In REST principles, each URL-root is one resource. You can do things from that resource, like rendering a certain view based on some bit of data, or you can add/modify data using a certain verb, or you can make flapjacks if that's your style. But all Person will always be at http://server.domain/app/Person, and not "some person commands are on http://server.domain/app/Person and some person commands are on http://server.domain/app/Department" because then you're just going to throw your arms up in the air and go "well how do I know where all to find people actions?!?!"

That, in a nutshell, is why you don't want to put some methods for accessing data on one controller (rendering the view) and some methods for accessing data on another controller (JSON) for the same resource-type.

---

Now that I've put all that braindump into a post, which parts am I fuzzy on? Feel free to edit the post and insert some `**what do you mean here?**` or `**you seem to be jumping around on this point a lot**` or whatever you feel is appropriate.

Comment: @jcolebrand That's an extraordinary answer.  Thank you. I now see a rough path to creating urls instead of adding the JSON string to the data parameter.  It will be more in keeping with Codeigniter's approach to generate urls like this:  app_root/instructors/add_tree_node/34/grammar and have a range of suitable controllers as I did before I started attempting Ajax with Codeigniter.

Comment: haha, thanks, I don't know if I would call it "extraordinary" but if it was at all informative, then I did well. You're welcome to ask any questions, and I can try and clarify, and maybe I've given you a structure to think about other things in the future. Be sure and look at how SO does things as you navigate the site, because they do MVC and have talented programmers working for them. I think my main point was "the url refers first to a resource, and then actions on that resource, not actions, that may have resources" and if you got that, then I did well ;-)

Comment: @Matt I thought jcolebrand's answer was extraordinary. I'm terribly grateful you took the trouble to put a bounty on it. It's going to take me months (I'm not a full-time developer) to grasp everything in the answer and implement it in my app.

Comment: Aww schucks you two, I'm just a simple man trying to spread ideas. David, my username is my gmail address, feel free to bug me with questions, but knowing it may take a day or two to get back to you. I can write for days on this stuff but sometimes I get out of sync on my topics. I've full well got a plan to write a book on this sort of thing, to introduce people to the concepts, but I'm currently going through a few medical issues which cause loss-of-concentration and motivation like people don't understand. So :-\ One day ... one day.

Comment: @jcolebrand I'll be thinking of you. The particularly useful thing about your answer is that it is so sensitively aimed at my level.  I can produce 1000s of lines of quite complex JavaScript and throw data around quite successfully; what I needed (and got) was a higher level of understanding of the architecture.  You rightly identified what level to pitch the answer. In English teaching, we talk about acquisition taking place when the teacher provides comprehensible input at i+1 (current level plus one) See, perhaps, http://esl.fis.edu/teachers/support/krashen.htm. You hit the spot.

Comment: Merci for the kind words. :D I do intend to teach at some point, and I work on that ability routinely (hence answering questions like this on SO and my desire to write a book on these things ~ Intro web programming, all the stuff everyone expects you to know already) .. Thanks for the link :D

Comment: @jcolebrand I found this highly specific tutorial to help me implement RESTful services in Codeigniter http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/ so that's great.  One question though, I'm fond of the UML and struggle away with it.  Do you know of a good link for advice on using that to model a RESTful service? Do you use any kind of diagramming to track the burgeoning tree of URLs as a system develops?

Comment: I don't use anything in particular, I just focus on what single task I'm working on right now. If someone asked me to tell what all the routes were in my system right now, I would write another app (I can share that if need be, what I've got now, but it's highly targeted so not entirely helpful in the general form) that would use reflection and recursion and just list out all the route names and their verb type, etc. Hell, a tool for this probably exists already. But I only focus on what I need at the time, and each controller is small enough still for us to manage. _so far_ ;-)

Comment: I also don't know where you brought UML into this, since I don't see it in the article, so I'll assume that's a separate issue. I don't generally use UML, as I don't have any super complex models. Everything is fairly simple and straightforward, and the classes are my model documentation. I'm sure that's not very enterprisey, but it's the way we do it here.

Comment: @jcolebrand The UML is just an interest of mine; it's not in the article I cited.  My original question hints at my feeling that I always end up swimming in complexity.  I keep thinking that some kind of diagram (hence the UML) might help me sort things out.  It could be that your sending me off in the RESTful direction will be a more effective way of helping me with the architecture than the UML ever was.

Comment: Yeah, I think that by building things in an MVC and RESTful way, that you'll soon find that resources have attributes and methods/actions, but that the methods are restricted to the controller (grabbing just method signatures makes it easy to build a list of what those methods/actions are), and the attributes are easily drawn from a model .cs file. (that's how I do it, my model-attributes are in their own CS file, and the model-data is in another file, so I don't clutter things up, and I can visualize structures pretty quickly)

Comment: @jcolebrand Are you talking about a .Net environment with C# files when you say .cs file? I've searched around and the only connection I can think of is C sharp.  Is this some other esoteric kind of file related to the RESTful approach? I'm just about to embark on a project using .Net 4, where I think the MVC approach is emphasised more than it used to be.